# How can I efficiently synchronize/comunicate two custom fields in Strapi without frequent local storage checks?

Tags: strapi

I have two custom fields in Strapi, and I want to establish interaction between them. For instance, custom field 2 should wait for custom field 1 to be filled in first, and then display data based on the input in custom field 1. Currently, I'm using local storage to achieve this, but I feel it's not optimal because there are checks happening every second.

Is there a more efficient or best-practice way to accomplish this goal without relying on local storage and reducing the frequency of checks? I want to improve the performance of my Strapi application and ensure smooth interaction between these two custom fields. Thank you very much for your assistance!

I've tried editing the file within node_modules, specifically in the `@strapi/admin/admin/src/content-manager/components/input.index.js.` I added a new prop to GenericInput. However, when I tried to use it, it resulted in individual useState for two custom fields.